# The import com.google.api.services.samples cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the Youtube Data API to receive some search results and I'm getting the following from eclipse..

[image]

I **can't find the class "Auth" anywhere** on the web, I don't understand why it can't be found.

Anyone know?

Comment: You can find the class in [these](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java) git repository.

Comment: @Jens could you make your comment an answer please? this solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the class in [these](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java) git repository